# Is 'using namespace' inside another namespace equivalent to an alias?

Tags: c++, namespaces

Consider the following two statements:

```
namespace foo = bar;
```

and

```
namespace foo {
  using namespace bar;
}
```

Are those two statements equivalent, or are there some subtle differences I'm not aware of?

(Please note that this is not a question about coding style - I'm just interested in C++ parsing).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
namespace foo=bar;
```

This does not affect any name lookup rules.  The only affect is to make 'foo' an alias to 'bar'.  for example:

```
namespace bar
{
  void b();
}

void f () {
  bar::b ();  // Call 'b' in bar
  foo::b ();  // 'foo' is an alias to 'bar' so calls same function
}
```

The following does change lookup rules

```
namespace NS
{
  namespace bar
  {
  }

  namespace foo {
    using namespace bar;

    void f () {
      ++i;
    }
  }
}
```

When lookup takes place for 'i', 'foo' will be searched first, then 'NS' then 'bar'.

Comment: Sorry for the very, very late comment, but I figured others might be searching.  The using namespace bar statement only brings those things defined at that time into the foo namespace.  In short, it can create bad order dependencies.  See item #59 in Sutter/Alexandrescu's C++ Coding Standards

Comment: @RobL:  A using _declaration_ only brings in the names declared at that time.  The above is a using _directive_.  The former is like a redeclaration of the names from the namespace into the current scope.  The latter is more like a rule to lookup saying, if you don't find it here then check this other namespace.

Answer (score 2):

As you are importing a namespace into another, then yes, it should be equal in that respect. However, the second one also allows for other code to be placed within, so you can also put things which are *not* part of namespace foo within it. The former merely creates an alias.

Comment: And if names are added into namespace 'foo' then the different lookup rules may result in different names being found between the two examples.